# Importar de Acces a Excel y tamaño de tabla dinámico

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access-2007

Cuando importo una tabla de `Access` a `Excel`, el rango de la tabla que quiero crear es fijo y no se adapta al número de columnas de la tabla en Access.

Si la tabla en Access coincide con el rango en `Excel` no hay problemas, pero cuando la tabla de `Access` tiene más campos la tabla que se crea en la hoja se queda corta.

> El procedimiento que tengo para importar una tabla se llama `ImportarDatos()`

```
Public Sub ImportarDatos()
    
    On Error GoTo Errohandler
    
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strVariablePath As String
    Dim adConn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim recSet As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strDB As String
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim strTabla As String
    Dim strVariableTabla As String
    Dim longCampos As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim strNombreHoja As String
    Dim strNombreTabla As String
    Dim strVariableNombreTabla As String
    
    strVariablePath = Range("TablaRutaBD")
    strPath = strVariablePath
    
    With adConn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .Properties("Data Source") = strPath
        .Properties("Jet OLEDB:Database Password") = ""
        .Open
    End With
   
    strVariableTabla = Range("TablaNombreTabla")
    strTabla = strVariableTabla
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & strTabla & " "
    
    recSet.Open strSQL, adConn
    
    strNombreHoja = Range("TablaNombreHoja")
    
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(strNombreHoja)
    
    strVariableNombreTabla = Range("TablaNombreExcel")
    strNombreTabla = strVariableNombreTabla
    ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$F$1"), , xlYes).name = strNombreTabla
    
    Sheets(strNombreHoja).Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset recSet
        
    longCampos = recSet.Fields.Count
    
    For i = 0 To longCampos - 1
        ws.Cells(1, i + 1).Value = recSet.Fields(i).name
    Next
    
    recSet.Close: Set recSet = Nothing
    adConn.Close: Set adConn = Nothing
    
Errohandler:
    
    If Error = 9 Then
        
        Resume
    
    End If
        
End Sub
```

La línea donde defino el número de columnas es este:

```
ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$F$1"), , xlYes).name = strNombreTabla
```

**¿Cómo puedo poner para que el rango se adapte al número de columnas?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ya he dado con la solución.

He sustituido la siguiente línea:

```
ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$F$1"), , xlYes).name = strNombreTabla
```

por esta otra

```
ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcQuery, recSet, Destination:=Selection).QueryTable.Refresh
```

Lo que estaba pasando es que no estaba usando bien los parámetros. Tenía que usar la opción `xlSrcQuery` en vez de `xlsSrcRange`. Al usar `xlSrcQuery` tengo luego que usar el array de datos que haya guardado con el RecordSet.

De esta manera además no tengo que leer el número de columnas y su valor para luego hacer un `for` e ir colocándolas una a una. Sencillamente con esta opción se trae directamente todas las columnas y sus valores y los convierte a una tabla de excel.

Como he hecho además algunos cambios dejo el código por si en un futuro a alguien le sirve.

```
Public Sub ImportarDatos()

    On Error GoTo Errohandler

    Dim strPath As String
    Dim adConn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim recSet As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strDB As String
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim strTabla As String
    Dim strNombreHoja As String

    strPath = Range("TablaRutaBD")

    With adConn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .Properties("Data Source") = strPath
        .Properties("Jet OLEDB:Database Password") = ""
        .Open
    End With

    strTabla = Range("TablaNombreTabla")
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & strTabla

    recSet.Open strSQL, adConn

    strNombreHoja = Range("TablaNombreHoja")

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(strNombreHoja)

    ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcQuery, recSet, Destination:=Selection).QueryTable.Refresh

    recSet.Close: Set recSet = Nothing
    adConn.Close: Set adConn = Nothing

Errohandler:

    If Error = 9 Then

        Resume

    End If

End Sub
```